# Pyspark SQL Replace Element With NULL

Tags: sql, database, replace, pyspark, sql-delete

I'm trying to write a sql query to use in pyspark to scrub information from a pyspark df. The df I want to modify looks like:

```
  hashed_customer     firstname    lastname    email   order_id    status          timestamp
      eater 1_uuid  1_firstname  1_lastname  1_email    12345    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 20:45:15
      eater 2_uuid  2_firstname  2_lastname  2_email    23456    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 20:29:22
      eater 3_uuid  3_firstname  3_lastname  3_email    34567    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 19:31:55
      eater 4_uuid  4_firstname  4_lastname  4_email    45678    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 17:49:27
```

I have another pyspark df with the customer I need to remove from the customer_temp_tb table that looks like this:

```
hashed_customer    eaterstatus
   eater 1_uuid      OPTED_OUT
   eater 3_uuid      OPTED_OUT
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query to use in pyspark that will remove the firstname, lastname, and email from the first table if the customer is in the second table. Kinda along the lines of:

```
UPDATE customer_temp_tb
SET firstname="", lastname="", email=""
WHERE hashed_eater_uuid IN
(SELECT hashed_eater_uuid FROM opt_out_temp_tb)
```

so that the end result would look like:

```
hashed_customer     firstname    lastname    email   order_id    status          timestamp
   eater 1_uuid           NaN         NaN      NaN    12345    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 20:45:15
   eater 2_uuid   2_firstname  2_lastname  2_email    23456    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 20:29:22
   eater 3_uuid           NaN         NaN      NaN    34567    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 19:31:55
   eater 4_uuid   4_firstname  4_lastname  4_email    45678    OPTED_IN     2020-05-14 17:49:27
```

The issue I seem to have is that pyspark does not support UPDATE. Is there another option for this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Show the results *after* your operation.  It is unclear if you want to remove rows or overwrite columns.

Answer (score 0):

I think , you can update columns as null or  string empty "" instead of delete .

Comment: I'm trying to do so in pyspark with an UPDATE query but I'm getting ```ParseException: '\nmismatched input \'UPDATE\' expecting``` ... error

Comment: I think you use  \  syntax in query . Try this :

Comment: spark.sql("""SELECT
  column1,
  Column2
FROM table1
WHERE column1 < 500""")

Comment: İn this article   show how to  replace column value to new value like update. may be you can this way. After your delete operation  , replace NaN value to new value or string empty/null  .  Here is the article : https://dwgeek.com/how-to-update-spark-dataframe-column-values-using-pyspark.html/